# How to trace indirect precedents in Excel?

Tags: excel, trace, excel-formula, operator-precedence

The Trace Precedents/Dependents buttons in Excel are extremely useful in analyzing the structure of a complex spreadsheet.

I have a sheet comprised of many calls whose precedents are generated programmatically, using reference functions like CELL(), OFFSET() etc., where the arguments to these functions are expressions.

When using the trace buttons, excel won't trace the cells that are not explicitly referred to in the formula.

Is there a way to get the full set of precedents of a specific cell?

Note: searching Google I saw an application in the Office Marketplace that is available for purchase and supposedly does that. I wonder if there is a way of doing so with the provided Excel functionality?

EDIT: here's an example: in cell M5 I have the following formula, which references D5, D13, and G6. G6 is calculated by the OFFSET() function, relative to G4.

```
=IMSUM($D5,IMPRODUCT($D13,OFFSET($G$4, 2*(ROW()-ROW($G$4)), 0)))
```

When tracing the cell's precedents, Excel does not show the G6 cell. Instead, it shows the base of the offset, which is G4.

Comment: Can you update your question with a few examples of some of your more-complex formulas?

Comment: the built-in tracing main purpose is to store the [recalculation chain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb687891.aspx?ppud=4) inside your excel file after you enter a formula - let's call it "on compile time" - but volatile functions are evaluated "on runtime" => you need a VBA macro or an add-in for 1-time evaluation of precedents of volatile functions

Comment: and i guess there is no such monster as "full set of precedents" if you would want to include volatile user defined functions or arbitrary combinations of regular functions like `offset(if(indirect(sumproduct(...`

Comment: @deathApril - if I were a developer of Excel, the approach I may take may be to do this analysis on runtime in a way that recalculates the sheet and record which are the (1st generation - I'm not looking for more than that) cells that contribute to the value of a cell. Iterating through all nontrivial formula cells will reveal the dependency structure of the sheet.

Answer (score 1):

a) reverse engineer the whole formula engine of Excel

b) write a VBA parser just for your case - i.e. get the arguments of OFFSET from the formula string and evaluate them

c) don't use volatile formulas if you can avoid it - like 
`=IMSUM($D5,IMPRODUCT($D13,INDEX($G$4:$G$999, 2*(ROW()-ROW($G$4)) + 1)))`

Comment: Thanks, as for b), I would need to parse every function that potentially references a cell indirectly, which is a lot of functions...

Comment: @ysap only every function you want to **use** to reference a cell indirectly ;)) i added option c) if you can use lookup functions instead of offset and named ranges instead of indirect...