# Find cells that depend indirectly on activecell (VBA)

Tags: vba, offset

I'd would like to find all cells(I will call it "target cells") that depend indirectly on activecell.
"Depend indirectly" means "target cells" depend on "activecell" through "Offset fuction" or "Indirect fuction"

Please refer to the exmaple below.

1. The address of activecell is "Sheet1!A2", and the value of that is 10.
2. The formula of "Sheet1!A3" is "=OFFSET(A1,1,0)"
3. If the value of "Sheet1!A2" is changed,
   the value of "Sheet1!A3" will be changed indirectly depending on "Sheet1!A2"

I'd like to code VBA that finds the cell "Sheet1!A3" indirectly depending on "Sheet1!A2".

Rf) I used "ShowDependents" method but can't find "target cells"..
That method can only find the cells that depend directly on activecell, Not indirectly.

Comment: You will basically have to parse formulas as suggested in the matching question  [How to trace indirect precedents in Excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10197443/how-to-trace-indirect-precedents-in-excel?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: @QHarr I guess you mean "using evaluate method". thank you.

Comment: Please post any code that you have tried